# How does $(document).ready() work in IE 8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I've recently installed IE 8 and can't seem to get the jquery $(document).ready event to fire.  Are there any special considerations that I'm missing?  Litterally, this is all I have in my html and it works as expected in Chrome and Firefox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Page full of awesomeness</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">        
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert("Hello?");           
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
```

In Internet Explorer, the page just loads without incident.  There's no alert box and I can't see any javascript errors reported.  Is this something normal that I just don't know about?

Comment: Check the w3c validator and you will see

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try turning this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" />
```

Into this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Correct.  IE fails hard on self-closing script tags. see: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-153-self-closing-script-tag-issues.html

Comment: It's hardly failure if its specified to work in such a way.. just because you get results doing it wrong doesn't mean you should use it.

Comment: That totally did it.  Thanks.  I probably would've never come up with that one.

Comment: Yep, I've had that problem with other browsers as well.

Answer (score 1):

With current XHTML strict standards:

Even when `src` is specified, the script tag is not an empty tag, and cannot be written `<script src=".... />`. If you include the `src` you should not include any script between the opening and closing tags as browser handling of any script between the tags is not reliable.

Basically, do not self close the tag. Use `</script>`.

Comment: From the XML specifications, these too notations are equivalent. That's a bug in IE.

Comment: It isn't a bug in IE. It is expecting a document served as `text/html` to be treated as XML. XHTML served as `text/html` is a hack and you have to follow the compatibility guidelines: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_1

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be this (sorry i don't have ie8 on this machine to test)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Page full of awesomeness</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">        
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert("Hello?");           
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
```

Also i'd suggest to use `/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js` if you are referring to your site's root

Comment: I wouldn't.  If you use /Script/jquery-1.3.2.js then your site won't work on a virtual web.

Comment: Yep, theres no reason to remove the ~, removing it will only make your application more brittle.

Comment: Well it was only my opinion. In the past i've had some issues with linking libraries in sites with heavy usage of "Human urls" so i prefer to link them with "/" (of course if they are under the site's domain root)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said, you're also missing the `</html>` at the end of the document. Maybe just a copy/paste error :)

Answer (score 0):

Also check the compatibility of jQuery. Currently jQuery 2.x only supports IE9 or later. Not IE8

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready()
```

Not work in IE8
I find a code sample from this link
https://plainjs.com/javascript/events/running-code-when-the-document-is-ready-15/
It is working with Jquery 1.10.2

```js
 function run() {
    // do something
    alert('working');
}

// in case the document is already rendered
if (document.readyState!='loading') run();
// modern browsers
else if (document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run);
// IE <= 8
else document.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', function(){
    if (document.readyState=='complete') run();
});
```