# Wiring document.ready event: IE behaving differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, document-ready

I am used to typing:  `$(function(){});` syntax to wire events and do other stuff in `document ready`event. But I noticed that IE8 was giving problems with calling functions from some included js files. I would not not have been able to crack it if the page did not have code from designer (he put some slideshow :D). The code for slideshow was using old `$(document).ready(function(){});` syntax and it was working. I removed my code and put it with slideshow init code and things started working.

I am not able to understand this strange behaviour, but want to make sure am not bitten by this bug again. Is it that included files are downloaded after `ready` event fires?

EDIT:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

$(function(){
    myCustomFunction(); ///THIS IS CAUSING EXCEPTION IN IE 8
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    myCustomFunction(); ///THIS IS WORKS IN IE 8
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The ready event only fires after all the included files have finished downloading, that's what it's for.

I also ran into a similar issue before, but it was due to my script tags not being closed properly, have a look here: [How does $(document).ready() work in IE 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747854/how-does-document-ready-work-in-ie-8)

Comment: Not is not what is stated in the linked question. jQuery is included for sure and `$(function(){})` is entered.

Answer (score 0):

The issues could be caused because JQuery has not yet been loaded, try running the following code before your $(document).ready code to test:

```
if (jQuery) alert('jquery loaded')
else alert('jquery not loaded')
```

We had a similar browser compatibility issue, can't remember if it was IE8.  It was caused by the script tags 'type' attribute.

We had some down labelled 'text/javascript' ([the W3C recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html)), 'application/javascript', and some with no type attribute.  JQuery was at the top of the header labelled 'text/javascript' but still loaded last.

The issue was easily solved by putting the same ContentType on all script tags

Comment: jQuery is loaded. it enters into `$(function(){})` but does not call the code inside this function that is from other included file.