# Append() does not work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, append, innerhtml

I'm trying to load HTML content dynamically in my website. It works in all browsers Except IE8.

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var mycontent14dec = '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/mtsconnects" target="_blank"><img src="../sliderbanners/nh7-livestreaming.jpg" width="589" height="309" /></a>' 
        + '<a href="../events/nh7/index.html"><img src="../sliderbanners/nh7-1.jpg" width="589" height="309" /></a>' 
        + '<a href="../events/nh7/index.html"><img src="../sliderbanners/nh7-2.jpg" width="589" height="309" /></a>' 
        + '<a href="http://www.mtsindia.in/justdongle/" target="_blank"><img src="../sliderbanners/Diwali_festival.jpg" width="589" height="309" /></a>';

    $(".addhtml").append(mycontent14dec);
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="addhtml"></div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors at all? Can you set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: this will probably solve your prob: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747854/how-does-document-ready-work-in-ie-8

Comment: here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GudtE/
pls help

Comment: @Matanya actually im using <script type="application/x-javascript" src="../js/start.js"></script>

Comment: or anyway to use DOM, I dont know DOM much

Comment: So this one (text/javascript is the only one supported accross all browsers. omit the type altogether because it defaults to text/javascript): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288263/why-doesnt-ie8-recognize-type-application-javascript-in-a-script-tag

Comment: so will it work if I remove the type ? I dont have Windows, I hv MAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the javascript TYPE, IE only supports type=**text/javascript**

@Matanya Thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 0):

It' might be the way you are formatting your variable, trey putting the html in one string all on one line, if it then works then that's your issue.