# Internet Explorer 8 Compatibilty jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

[image: IE 8 Error]

Hi, Im just wondering if someone can help me on this, i keep getting this in IE8, ive been through the jQuery and checked it all for errors, i did have a couple too many ,'s after options and a few after brackets but no matter what i try i can not get it to recognise the $  code as below...

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    /* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*  1.  Main Slider (Revolution Slider)
    /* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    $('.revslider').revolution( {  <-- THIS IS LINE 31
        delay                 : 9000,
        startwidth            : 1120,
        startheight           : 535,

        onHoverStop           : "on",                   // Stop Banner Timet at Hover on Slide on/off

        thumbWidth            : 100,                    // Thumb With and Height and Amount (only if navigation Tyope set to thumb !)
        thumbHeight           : 50,
        thumbAmount           : 3,

        hideThumbs            : 200,
        navigationType        : "none",                 //bullet, thumb, none, both  (No Shadow in Fullwidth Version !)
        navigationArrows      : "verticalcentered",     //nexttobullets, verticalcentered, none
        navigationStyle       : "round",                //round,square,navbar

        touchenabled          : "on",                   // Enable Swipe Function : on/off

        navOffsetHorizontal   : 0,
        navOffsetVertical     : 20,

        stopAtSlide           : -1,                     // Stop Timer if Slide "x" has been Reached. If stopAfterLoops set to 0, then it stops already in the first Loop at slide X which defined. -1 means do not stop at any slide. stopAfterLoops has no sinn in this case.
        stopAfterLoops        : -1,                     // Stop Timer if All slides has been played "x" times. IT will stop at THe slide which is defined via stopAtSlide:x, if set to -1 slide never stop automatic

        fullWidth             : "on",

        shadow                : 0
    });
```

Comment: If you are getting jQuery errors on IE8 you are probably using jQuery 2.x like maja says. Try to switch to jQuery 1.x (it's the same as 2.x but has support for IE6+)

Comment: Do you have a proper `DOCTYPE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jQuery` instead of `$`, leading to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.revslider').revolution( {
        ...
```

Also note that `jQuery 2.x` doesn't support IE8 - [see here](https://jquery.com/browser-support/).

You need to use `jQuery 1.x` for support of IE6+.

Also check if you include your scripts correctly - see this question: [How does $(document).ready() work in IE 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747854/how-does-document-ready-work-in-ie-8)

Comment: The error still remains, thats in compatibility mode and not

Comment: @MichaelGorman I updated my answer. Post your HTML if this doesn't solve your problem.